# Event handling with manually instantiated component

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to manually instantiate a Vuejs component, but can't get it to pass on events to its parent component.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input :value='value' @input='updateValue($event.target.value)'>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    props: ['value'],
    methods: {
      updateValue: function (value) {
        this.$emit('input', value);
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

The component is initialised by

```
var ComponentClass = Vue.extend(Component);
var instance = new ComponentClass({
  propsData: {
    value: this.modelValue
  }
});
instance.$mount();
document.getElementById('app').appendChild(instance.$el)
```

The problem is that `this.modelValue` is not updated automatically as `this._events` (in the component) does not contain any listeners. However, when I add the component in the template it works as expected (`this.modelValue` from the parent component gets updated).
Is there anything else that needs to be done when a component gets instantiated manually?

Answer (score 6):

You have to listen for the `input` event. That's what `v-model` does.

Try the code below:

```js
var ComponentClass = Vue.extend(Component);
var instance = new ComponentClass({
  propsData: {
    value: this.modelValue
  }
});
instance.$mount();
instance.$on('input', (e) => this.modelValue = e);    // <============ added this line
document.getElementById('app').appendChild(instance.$el)
```